# NSProgressIndicator progress with For loops?

Tags: objective-c, nsprogressindicator

My application does a lot of work with a bunch of For loops. It calculates a massive amount of strings, and it can take over a whole minute to finish.

So I placed a NSProgressIndicator in my app.

Within the loops, I used the "incrementBy" function of the NSProgressIndicator. However, I don't see the actual bar filling up.

I suspect that's because of the loops taking all power possible, and thus the NSProgressIndicator is not updated (graphically).

How would I make it progress then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are your `for` loops running on the main thread or in a background thread? If they're running on the main thread, the GUI will never get a chance to update itself to reflect the progress change as this will only happen at the end of the runloop, i.e. after your functions have finished running.

If your `for` loops are running in the background, you're being naughty! You shouldn't update the GUI from anywhere but the main thread. If you're targeting a modern system, you can use GCD to trivially work around this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // do stuff
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            // do your ui update here
        });
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite your `for` loops to take advantage of GCD even further and use `dispatch_apply`. The equivalent of the above would be:

```
dispatch_apply(n, DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, ^(size_t i) {
    // for loop stuff here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        // do your ui update here
    });
});
```

Note that using [`dispatch_apply`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_apply.3.html) means that each "iteration" of the loop *may* run concurrently with respect to one another, so this won't be applicable if your `for` loop requires to be run in a serial fashion.