# NSProgressIndicator not showing progress

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, nsprogressindicator

I have a for loop running on my main runloop.  I'm trying to have a progress indicator to show what's happening.  The problem is the UI never gets a chance to be updated.

I've looked at [NSProgressIndicator progress with For loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142183/nsprogressindicator-progress-with-for-loops) but I can't use their solution.  My for loop must be on the main thread - otherwise other parts of my program must be serial to the for loop.

Any ideas on how to force a redraw of the indicator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send your progress indicator a `displayIfNeeded` message (a method of `NSView`).