# Is there an easy way to update progressbar as code runs

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nstextfield, nsprogressindicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSProgressIndicator progress with For loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142183/nsprogressindicator-progress-with-for-loops)

I have a simple question this time (hopefully). I have an NSProgressIndicatorView (progress bar) and I want to update its value and a status label as a for loop runs:

```
for(int i=0; i<[nameArr count]; i++)
{
    NSString* str = [nameArr objectAtIndex:i];
    [text setStringValue:str];
    [status setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Processing names...%d of %ld",(i+1),[nameArr count]]];
    [progress setDoubleValue:i];
}
```

This code works, but the status label and the progress bar do not update until the entire for loop has finished. I can watch things work as it runs if I send them as an `NSLog`, so I assume there should be an easy way (without creating an `NSOperation`) to similarly update my status label and progress bar as I go.

Any ideas?

Comment: search first, ask questions later

Comment: I did surface searching on Google and S.O. before I asked my question...and I thought S.O. encouraged the whole "Q&A" answer your own question approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging, the UI can be updated asynchronously through for loops with the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        //Run for loop stuff here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
           //Run UI updates in here 
        });
    }
});
```